# Convert raw query to sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize and I'm having a hard time to understand this. This is my raw query:

```
select * from routes r join transports t where origin like :origin and destination like :destination and convert(departure, date) like convert(:date, date) and r.transportId = t.id
```

I want to do this in Sequelize, and looking at the docs I have tried this:

```
const { Sequelize, Op } = require("sequelize");
Route.findAll({
            where: {
                destination,
                origin,
                Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', Sequelize.col('departure'), 'date'): {
                        [Op.like]: Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', date, 'date'))
                }
            },
           include: [{
                model: db.transport,
                as: 'transport'
            }]);
```

But I get syntax errors.

Edit:

```
Route.findAll({
        where: {
            destination,
            origin,
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', Sequelize.col('departure'), 'date'), {
                [Op.like]: Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', date, 'date')
            })
        },
        include: [{
            model: db.transport,
            as: 'transport'
        }]
    });
```

I still get same syntax error:

```
 Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', Sequelize.col('departure'), 'date'), {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Edit:

```
Route.findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.and]: [
                { destination, origin },
                Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', Sequelize.col('departure'), 'date'), {
                    [Op.like]: Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', date, 'date')
                })
            ]
        },
        include: [{
            model: db.transport,
            as: 'transport'
        }]
    });
```

It removed the previous syntax error. Now I get this one:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''date') LIKE CONVERT('2020-05-28 00:00:00', 'date'))' at line 1
```

Comment: Can you paste the error log that appears with the syntax errors? I also suggest you to avoid at all costs doing JOINs based on string compares, and start doing them based on IDs of the given registers.

Comment: @RamiroOlivencia, i guess no need - it is obvious problem with brackets in where closure

Answer (score 2):

just format it properly

```
Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', Sequelize.col('departure'), 'date'),
  {
    [Op.like]: Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', 'date', date)
  }
)
```

```
where: {
  [Op.and]: [ 
    { destination: {[Op.like]: destination }},
    { origin: {[Op.like]: origin }},
    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', Sequelize.col('departure'), 'date'), 
    {
      [Op.like]: Sequelize.fn('CONVERT', date, 'date')
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: you were right I had some mistakes with my brackets but I still get a syntax error. Check it out now.

Comment: @User1, that is another error, has nothing to do with topic, it is error in sql text generated by sequelize. Check CONVERT syntax, may be parameters you provided are wrong

Comment: @User1, i guess you should swap 'date' and date

Comment: it is not that. My raw query uses the convert function and works just fine. It is related to the topic since my problem still is that I can't get my raw query to be a sequelize query. Thanks tho.

Comment: @User1, Sure? Because in documentation type goes first `CONVERT(data_type(length), expression, style)`

Comment: Yes, it's weird I have seen the documentation you are mentioning. But it won't work that way, but I swap it it works. Anyway I have tried to swap it again so that it matches the documentation and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. I finally had to use [Sequelize.literal](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal) to make it work:

```
Route.findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.and]: [
                { destination },
                { origin },
                Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('CONVERT(departure, date)'), {
                    [Op.like]: Sequelize.literal('CONVERT("' + date + '", date)')
                })
            ]
        },
        include: [{
            model: db.transport,
            as: 'transport'
        }]
    });
```